# Where is the leather working trainer in Warsong hold?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have looked around in Warsong hold, but I cannot locate the leather working trainer. There appears to be every other profession trainer in there. Where is the leather trainer? I searched bit on the internet and found this page http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Leatherworking_trainers, from  what I can see there is a leather trainer in Dalaran, is there only one in the whole of Northrend?

Comment: There are more than those in Dalaran.. give me a sec to point them out.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing that you look for a trainer in *Warsong Hold* I guess you don't need the Alliance ones. Here are the leather working trainers accessible to Horde players located in *Northrend*.

The closest one actually is right there in the *Borean Tundra*:
Just look for **Awan Iceborn** in *Taunka'Le Village* (Coords 76,37)
[image: Borean Tundra]

Another one is in *Icecrown*:
**Kul'de** is with his colleagues on the *Argent Tournament Grounds* and accessible to Horde and Alliance players (71, 21)
[image]

The last one of the trainers not located in *Dalaran* is in the *Howling Fjord*:
**Gunter Hansen** will wait for you in the starting area of the Horde of that region, Vengeance Landing (78, 28)
[image]

Just for the record, Alliance players have a similar amount and location of leather working trainers:

- **Rosemary Bovard** in Valiance Keep, Borean Tundra
- **Bernadette Dexter** in Valgarde, Howling Fjord
- the neutral **Kul'de** in Icecrown mentioned above